# Angular2 many components on the same route

Tags: angular, router

Please help me with an ideea because i didn't find anything about this.
I want to have a component in the first route, and in my second route i want to keep that component and i want to add one more without reload my first component because i have an iframe inside it.
I did it with two router-outlets but i need to do it with only one router outlet. Here is my code:

main component template:

```
<nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['route1']">route1</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['route2']">route2</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

and my @RouteConfig([

    {
        path: '/route1',
        component: IframeComponent
    },

    {
        path: '/route2',
        name: 'Products',
        component: IframeComponent /// and here i need to add one more
    }
])
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Well it should work, if you just put the "other" component as a child component, and put the `router-outlet` inside your IframeComponent html, then it would be inside the iframe??

Comment: You are right, thanks

Comment: Put it up as an answer, if you do not mind accepting it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make your `route2`-component as a child-component, and add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside your parent-component `IframeComponent`, that will make that the "other" component will render inside your `IframeComponent`.

```
    {
        path: 'route1',
        component: IframeComponent
        children: [
           {
            path: 'route2',
            component: TheOtherComponent
        ]
    }
```